# Laravel Api.php route group naming conventions

Tags: laravel

I have a group definition inside api.php.
I wonder why the first controller works fine
but the second would return Target class [UserExpertController] does not exist. 
I like the second syntax more as im used to it from writing web.php routes.
any idea?!

```
 Route::name('experts.')->prefix('experts')->group(function () {
    // returns all experts
    Route::get('/',[UserExpertController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
```

//or

```
 Route::get('/','UserExpertController@index')->name('index');
```

Comment: The ::class syntax does not work because laravel adds the Controller namespace automatically, you can use `'Admin\UserExpertController'` and it will add the controller namespace + Admin section

Answer (score 0):

actually this works

```
    Route::get('/',[UserExpertController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
```

this doesn't work

```
 Route::get('/','UserExpertController@index')->name('index');
```